# mongodb filter not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, feathersjs

I am trying to run a query against my database as below:

```
filter.customerProfile = { $exists: true };
console.log("filter: " + JSON.stringify(filter));
this.accountsAPI.find(filter, cb);
```

in the callback i print:

```
console.log('first element: ', JSON.stringify(accounts[0]));
```

my output:

```
filter: {"customerProfile":{"$exists":true}}
first element:  {"username":"aabrahams","firstName":"Arthur","lastName":"Abrahams","DOB":"1981-07-11","email":"aabrahams@gmail.com","adminProfile":[{"displayUsername":"Art Abrahams","active":true,"priceEdits":[],"products":[],"productEdits":[],"jobCancellationApprovals":[],"partnerApprovals":[]}],"_id":"TkJNoSogUaJFKIHU"}
```

Basically, it returns all users, not only those with a "customerProfile" and what filter I use does not even matter. I tried adding "$ne":null and it did not help.

Comment: Can you share a better-formed piece of code? Like what is this.accountsAPI.

Comment: accountsAPI is a service provided by feathers.

Comment: feathers mongo interface exports: find(params, cb): void;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [feathers' documentation](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-mongodb#filter-criteria) you make a filter criteria with **query**:

```
var filter = {
  query: {
    customerProfile: { 
      $exists: true 
    }
  }
}
this.accountsAPI.find(filter, cb);
```

Comment: Yup that should do it!